# Combo box inside grid control item repeating when scrolling windows8 xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, devexpress

I am having a xaml combobox in datatemplete inside grid control in which when I am scrolling the selected value of the combobox repeats for some rows.ie) The selected values will be saved in db when its index changed. Next time when I am loading it again the visible rows shows the selected values correctly. but when am scrolling the gridcontrol down, the values are repeating. how could I make it to work properly? I am using devexpress gridcontrol.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the component. Have you posted a bug report?

Comment: Not yet.. How can I raise this bug report?